# $Swipe.Bind Unreliable On Calling Move Event - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas, angular-touch

I'm trying to make a **Canvas** that allows drawing on it.

I'm using **AngularJS** with **Angular-Touch** but it seems to be calling the cancel event frequently.

I think it has to do with the swipe buffer that determines if its a swipe or a scroll, but I'm not sure how to fix that.

Here's some code I've put down and it works sometimes but it is, like I said before, unreliable.

**AngularJS:**

```
var canvas=angular.element('canvas');

var canvasCord=function(canvas){
    return angular.element(canvas).offset();
};

var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
this.ctx=ctx;

$swipe.bind(angular.element('canvas'),{

    start:function(cord,event){

      event.preventDefault();
      cord=convertCord(cord,event.target);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(cord.x,cord.y);
      ctx.lineWidth='5';
      console.log('start');

   },move:function(cord,event){

      event.preventDefault();
      cord=convertCord(cord,event.target);
      ctx.lineTo(cord.x,cord.y);
      ctx.stroke();
      console.log('move');

  },end:function(cord,event){

      event.preventDefault();
      console.log(event);
      console.log(cord);
      cord=convertCord(cord,event.target);
      ctx.lineTo(cord.x,cord.y);
      ctx.stroke();
      console.log('end');

  },cancel:function(event){

      event.preventDefault();
      console.log(event);

  }
},["mouse","touch"]);

var convertCord=function(cord,canvas){

    var offcord=canvasCord(canvas);
    cord.x=cord.x-offcord.left;
    cord.y=cord.y-offcord.top
    console.log(cord);
    return cord;
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class='canvas'>
<canvas height='500' width='500'></canvas>
</div>
```

I think it's possible going into **Angular-Touch.js** file and simply increase the buffer size but, is there a cleaner way to do it?  And ngTouch is already in the module dependencies so it isn't dealing with that.

**update**

If found that was causes it to call the cancel even is that it moves more in the y direction then the x and is beyond the 10 px buffer. So I'm just looking for a clean way to increase the 10 px buffer.

Comment: To integrate AngularJS with touch events use [ngTouch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch).

Comment: Ngtouch is already part of the module I was just showing reduced code

Comment: Like I said it works it's just buggy.